# How to submit form using Spring weblow

Tags: spring, forms, spring-webflow

Below is my code snippet from jsp & flow xml, while trying to submit the form my page is getting refreshed but request is not going to the server. Please assist.

```
Jsp

<form action="${flowExecutionUrl}" modelAttribute="employeeDto" method="post">
<div class="formButton">
    <input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}" /> 
    <input  name="_eventId_nextBtn" type="submit" value="submit">
</div>
</form>


Flow xml

<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.4.xsd">

<var name="employeeDto" class="com.school.transferobjects.EmployeeDto"/>
<view-state id="employeeView" model="employeeDto" view="employee">
    <transition on="nextBtn" to="createEmployee" />
</view-state>

    <action-state id="createEmployee">
        <evaluate   
        expression="employeeHelper.saveEmployee(flowRequestContext,employeeDto)"
         result="flowScope.res"/>

        <transition on="${flowScope.res.success=='success'}" to="student.do"/> 
    </action-state>

</flow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think eventId is not being recognized, and so when you submit by click of the button and eventId is not found, resulting in flow execution getting refreshed.
Make sure you include form tag:

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
    <form:form modelAttribute="yourModel" method="post">
    ...
    </form:form>
```

Comment: I tried adding this tag also, but all in vain, mainly am surprised because, if I replace <input>  tag with <a > the code works, thus I think something else is creating a problem.

Comment: The problem was with one of the imports, issue resolved.